# Scrolling QScrollBar content by mouse movement while center button click

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

We have this example of a simple [Image Viewer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-imageviewer-example.html) from Qt website. Here an Image is displayed using a QLabel pixmap into a QScrollBar. I want to add the possibility to scroll the QScrollBar content (the image itself) when the mouse is moved while mouse center button is clicked.

How can I add this functionality?

Comment: Call `setDragMode(ScrollHandDrag)` on the `mouseClicked` event, after you check which mouse button was clicked (in the viewer class)

Comment: @Thalia Sorry but I don't understand. ScrollHandDrag is a DragMode of a QGraphicsView, but in the example there is no QGraphicsView but a QLabel.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not look at the sample and assumed the image may be loaded into a `QGraphicsView` or something similar. But I don't understand the question - running the sample, the image scrolls with the mouse wheel. Do you want to replace this functionality to a mouse move with the center button pressed ? If so... that's what you should implement

Comment: @Thalia The image actually scrolls with the mouse wheel (just vertical scrolling). I want to add a new functionality, scroll (vertical and horizontal scrolling) with the mouse movement while the central button of the mouse is pressed.